# Break array into multiple arrays based on first character in values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have the following javascript array:

```
var data = ["2_000001", "1_000001", "2_000002", "1_000002", "1_000003", "2_000003", "2_000004", "1_000004", "1_000005", "2_000005"]
```

How can I make 2 new arrays (or more if there are more elements with eg. 3_ or 4_ as identifier) like this:

```
var 2 = ["2_000001", "2_000002", "2_000003", "2_000004", "2_000005"]
var 1 = ["1_000001", "1_000002", "1_000003", "1_000004", "1_000005"]
```

I have so far:

```
data.forEach(function (str) {

    str_api = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('_'));
    console.log(str_api);
    a_api.push(str_api);
    clean_api = $.unique(a_api);

    str_id = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
    console.log(str_id);

});
```

Its not really close to the goal yet. Any help welcome!

Comment: You'll have a really bad time if you try to use numbers as identifiers, consider using an _Array_ or _Object_ instead if you need indicies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an *Arrow Function*

```
var obj = {};
data.forEach((e, i) => (i = parseInt(e, 10), obj[i] ? obj[i].push(e) : (obj[i] = [e])));

obj;
/* {
    "1": ["1_000001","1_000002","1_000003","1_000004","1_000005"],
    "2": ["2_000001","2_000002","2_000003","2_000004","2_000005"]
} */
```

- `(e, i) => expr` is a *Function* which takes two parameters, `e` and `i` (here we just want `i` scoped)
- `(expr1, expr2)` is two expressions making use of the comma operator `,`
- `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3` means if `expr1` truthy, do `expr2`, otherwise do `expr3`
- `parseInt` will truncate for us as `_` is an invalid number character
- `arr.forEach` applies a function to every item in an *Array*

Answer (score 3):

Genrating variables on the go will not a be a good idea so either use a `Object` or `Multi Dimensional Array`

```
    var data = ["2_000001", "1_000001", "2_000002", "1_000002", "1_000003", "2_000003", "2_000004", "1_000004", "1_000005", "2_000005"];

    var arr = {};

    // Loop through array
    [].forEach.call(data, function(inst){

        var x = inst.split("_")[0];

        // Check if arr already has an index x, if yes then push
        if(arr.hasOwnProperty(x)) 
            arr[x].push(inst);

        // Or else create a new one with inst as the first element.
        else 
            arr[x] = [inst];


    });
```

Explanation of code is written as comments.

This will result in

```
{
    "2": ["2_000001", "2_000002", "2_000003", "2_000004", "2_000005"],

    "1": ["1_000001", "1_000002", "1_000003", "1_000004", "1_000005"]
}
```

Which you can use in anyway you want.

Comment: Why are you `.call`ing an _Array_ method on an _Array_ (`[].forEach.call(foo, bar)`) instead of invoking through itself normally (`foo.forEach(bar)`)?

Answer (score 1):

This creates an object with properties and the values you want.

```
var data = ["2_000001", "1_000001", "2_000002", "1_000002", "1_000003", "2_000003", "2_000004", "1_000004", "1_000005", "2_000005"];

// Initialize a new object
var arrays = {};

// Loop over data
data.forEach(function (str) {

    // Get id piece
    str_api = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('_') + 1);

    // check if existing property for this id, if not initialize new array
    if (!arrays[str_api]) {
        arrays[str_api] = [];
    }

    // get value piece
    str_id = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);

    // add to that id's array
    arrays[str_api].push(str_id);

});

console.log(arrays);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/6e2bLgf5/

Output:

```
{
    2_: ["000001", "000002", "000003", "000004", "000005"],
    1_: ["000001", "000002", "000003", "000004", "000005"]
}
```

EDIT: Not sure if you want the underscore or not in the property name. In your description you give 3_ 4_ as examples but in code example you give 1 2.